# Flattening a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to flatten an arbitrary number of lists inside lists in Haskell. I know this question has been posted up on Stack before, but the answers on there are either too complicated for me (I'm new to Haskell), or not an answer satisfying my needs (e.g. concat won't work for me because I have to actually write this flatten function myself for an exam study guide). I'm also writing my own flatten function in Haskell to understand maybe why the top solutions uses Modules.

Here's what I have so far.

```
flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten [] = []
flatten (x:xs) = flatten x:flatten xs
```

However, I get an error:

```
Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : flatten
*** Expected type : [[a]] -> [a]
*** Inferred type : [[[a]]] -> [[a]]
```

EDIT: Sorry! I misunderstood my exam study question. All elements of the list actually have to be lists. For example,
`[[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [7,8,9]]` and not `[1, [2,3,4]]`.

Comment: Try to define the type of your function. Your above definition has conflicts in the types.

Comment: Hmm, so I defined it as `flatten :: [a] -> [a]` but it's complaining that `[a] -> [[a]]` does not match `[a] -> [a]` and still, unification would give infinite type. Why is this?

Comment: I'm afraid you like to flatten a list like `[1,[2,3]]` which is not a correctly typed list in the first place. It is really a tree and you would need a `datatype` to define it.

Comment: If your exam study guide is specific to Haskell, I'm afraid you are still misunderstanding it.  You can't make a Haskell list like the ones you describe in your EDIT -- every element of the list must be the same type, and a list-of-integers is not the same type as a list-of-list-of-integers.

Comment: @comingstorm That actually makes sense. Now I have no idea where to start approaching this problem..

Comment: Hmm, answered the question just before you edited.  Now I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Can you clarify what you mean by "list" -- do you mean the Haskell datatype `[a]`, in which case Bryan and comingstorm are right, or can it be your own datatype?

Comment: If your exam study guide is *not* specific to Haskell, then you should be aware that, even though a large number of dynamically-typed languages permit heterogeneous lists, Haskell doesn't -- not like that, at least.  You *can* do it in Haskell if you make your own type such as `data Tree = Leaf Int | Node [Tree]`

Comment: Um, be aware that Haskell is a *statically*-typed language, not a dynamically-typed one.  Heterogeneous lists are natural in dynamically-typed languages, but not so much in the likes of Haskell or C...

Answer (score 11):

**Step 1:  define your data.**  You need a datatype that supports arbitrary nesting.  `[a]` does not, so you will not be able to solve the problem that way.

So what will the data look like?  How about some Lisp notation:

```
a
()
(a b c)
((a b) c d)
(a (b c) d (e (f)))
```

Looks like an element can either be an atom, or a list.  So let's say the previous sentence in Haskell:

```
data Element t = -- "an element is either ..."
    = Atom t     -- "an atom ..."
    | List [Element t]  -- "or a list of elements"
  deriving (Show)       -- "and please print things for me too, okay?"
```

**Step 2: traversing the data.**  Now you need to write a function that flattens an `Element t` into a list.  What's the type signature going to look like?

I'd suggest `flatten :: Element t -> [t]`.  To implement it, it's going to need two cases -- one for `Atom`s, and one for `List`s:

```
flatten :: Element t -> [t]
flatten (Atom x) = ....
flatten (List xs) = .....
```

Remember that each equation has to evaluate to a `[t]`.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm still new to Haskell, and I'm not sure what an atom is. I couldn't find any relevant information online, either.

Comment: @user1831442 [it's a Lisp term](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Lisp-Atoms.html).  It just means a datum that's not a list.

Comment: I don't think I have anymore time to figure out how to implement this, could you please just give me a quick and dirty implementation of this?

Comment: @user1831442 sorry, no. That's not what StackOverflow is for.  But a hint:  check out [`++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-).

Answer (score 6):

Let's work out the type of your function: if you have a list of lists, this is written `[[a]]`. You want to flatten this to just a list, `[a]`, so the type of flatten should be `[[a]] -> [a]`. You could also cheat and lookup the type of `concat`, since you know you are re-implementing that.

Now lets look at the implementation. The first case matches `[]` and returns `[]`. Does this conform to `[[a]] -> [a]`? Yes, because the parameter `[]` is an empty list of type `[something]` where something can have the type `[a]`. The return value also conforms to our type because it's an empty list of type `[whatever]` where whatever can have type `a`.

Now lets look at the second case, does it match the type `[[a]] -> [a]`? Pattern matching with `(x:xs)` means `x` has the type `[a]` and `xs` has the type `[[a]]`, this is fine. The problem is your recursive calls: the first one calls `flatten` with `x` which has type `[a]`. But we know flatten's parameter must be of type `[[a]]`.

By the way, you will often get clearer or more precise type error messages if you declare the type of your function first. This is because the compiler can immediately stop once it finds a contradiction with what you declared. If you elide the signature, the compiler only checks that the definition is consistent with itself. When I declare the type GHC tells me:

```
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a0]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for flatten :: [[a]] -> [a] at x.hs:20:1
    Expected type: [[a0]]
      Actual type: [a]
    In the first argument of `flatten', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `flatten x'
```

This is exactly what we found checking the type ourselves, manually. The argument we passed to `flatten` should have type `[[a]]` but we were actually passing a value of type `[a]`.

Comment: Woops, had to change the question around a bit. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Now that you have settled on the type of your function, carefully examine the types of your function definitions. You will find that both the first and third clause of your function do not comply.

Comment: I think I see now. You can't write this function this way because the arguments keep changing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in Haskell all nested lists have a uniform nesting depth for all elements.  This is a consequence of the type system, which requires all of the elements of a list to be of the same type.

Something like the following definition could never typecheck:

```
example = [1, [2, 3, 4], [[5, 6], [7]]]
```

The first element is `1 :: Integer`, second one is `[2, 3, 4] :: [Integer]`, and so on.

The same problem applies to your edited example:

```
[[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [7,8,9]]
```

The first element of this list would have a type like `[[Integer]]`, while the second one would have something like `[Integer]`.  But this is not allowed.

Second thing: it's not just that the lists can't have a non-uniform depth, there also cannot exist a function that will "look" at different nested lists at different depths.  A function of a type like `[[a]] -> [a]` will "peel" one level of nesting off its input list, but will treat `a` as an opaque type—it doesn't know what type `a` is, so if you pass an `[[[Integer]]]` argument, `flatten` cannot exploit the fact that `a` is `[Integer]` for that one argument you gave it—`a` could be anything!

So the only list flattening that can be done in Haskell is to remove nesting at some depth fixed by the function's type.  So for example, `flatten` peels off just one level of nesting, and using function composition we can peel off two or more: `flatten . flatten :: [[[a]]] -> [a]`, `flatten . flatten . flatten :: [[[[a]]]] -> [a]`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

`[[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [7,8,9]]` is not a valid Haskell list either. It contains two elements; the first is `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` which is a `[[Int]]`, and the second is just `[7,8,9]`, which is just `[Int]`.

A list in Haskell is always of type `[a]`, for some `a` which has to be **the same** for all elements of the list. This means that if you're dealing with nested lists, every element must have the same degree of nesting.

It seems unlikely that a basic Haskell exam would ask you to flatten arbitrary levels of nesting. It almost certainly just wants to you to implement `flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]`, which you can tell from the type only removes one "level" of list. You can call it on lists like `[[[1], [[2]], [[3]]]`, which is of type `[[[Int]]`, but the type clearly says that the result will be `[[Int]]`, i.e. it will return `[[1], [2], [3]]`, not `[1, 2, 3]`.

The problem with what you're trying to do is that when your `flatten` receives its argument of type `[[a]]` and splits it into `(x:xs)` (unless it was empty), the `x` will be an element of that `[[a]]` list, so it will have type `[a]`. You're then trying to call `flatten` on it so you that you can flatten "all the way down", but `flatten` takes an argument of type `[[a]]` and `x` is of type `[a]`.

Another way to think about why this couldn't work is that if it *did* work, you'd eventually get to the last "level" of list, and `x` wouldn't even be a list type at all. But you'd then pass it to `flatten` again, which would try to match it against either of the patterns `[]` or `(x:xs)`, and have to fail. The type errors you're getting are what prevents this from occurring.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which can flatten arbitrary deep nested lists, but the nesting level must be consistent (at least if you want to stay with lists):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances
  , OverlappingInstances
  , IncoherentInstances  #-}

class Nested a where
  flatten :: [a] -> [Int]

instance Nested Int where
  flatten = id

instance (Nested a) => Nested [a] where
  flatten xss = concatMap flatten xss

-- e.g. now this works ...
flatten [[1 :: Int,2,3],[2,3,4]]   
-- ... and this too ...
flatten [[[1 :: Int,2,3],[2,3,4]],[[25]]]   
-- ... but this won't work
-- flatten [[[1 :: Int,2,3],[2,3,4]],25]
```

If you want to allow arbitrary nesting, you have to wrap your types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification }

class Foo a

instance Foo Int

instance Foo [a]

data F = forall a. Foo a => F a

test = F [F (1 :: Int), F [F (2 :: Int), F [F (3 :: Int), F [F (4 :: Int)]]]]
```

Now you could write a `flatten` for such a type.

However, I wouldn't recommend to explore this as a beginner. First you need a better understanding concerning how types actually *should* work. This stuff just isn't trivial, it goes against the grain of Haskell's type system, so every explanation *will* confuse you. Try to use the types in a way they are intended to use, and come back to such questions when you are really comfortable with the common use cases.

Comment: This answer is quite interesting. I'd like to learn more about classes and instances. Could you recommend something to read? Also - would a language implementing dependent types like Idris (where types can be passed as arguments to functions) be more suitable to implement such a flattening of lists of arbitrary depth?

Comment: @exchange I'm sorry, this is a very old answer, and I didn't work with Haskell for a long time, so my knowledge is very likely outdated. There might be even more elegant ways to write this in today's Haskell.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer anyways! I recently asked this question which is related and there are indeed some alternative implementations - but seem in part still close to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880676/is-flattening-a-list-easier-in-dependently-typed-functional-programming-language