# Is flattening a list easier in dependently typed functional programming languages?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coq, agda, idris

While looking for a function in haskell that flattens arbitrarily deeply nested lists, i.e. a function that applies `concat` recursively and stops at the last iteration (with a non-nested list), I noted that this would require to have a more flexible type system because with varying list depth, the input type varies as well. Indeed, there are several stackoverflow question - such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559889/flattening-a-list-in-haskell) one - in which the responses state that "there cannot exist a function that will 'look' at different nested lists at different depths".

EDIT: Some answers provide workarounds in haskell, either for custom data types or with the help of `TypeFamilies` or `MultiParamTypeClasses` (as in the answer by Noughtmare below or the answer by 'Landei' in the [post above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559889/flattening-a-list-in-haskell) or the answer by 'John L' in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994051/is-there-a-function-to-flatten-a-nested-list-of-elements/5994717#5994717) post).
However, those Families and Classes also seem to have been introduced for the lack of / to substitute dependent types in haskell (for example, the [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families) states *"Type families are [...] much like dependent types"*.

My question now is if it is true that haskell was indeed *originially* not made for defining such functions (that e.g. flatten lists of different depths) and, furthermore, if such problems would vanish once one moved to a language that implements [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)? (For example Idris, Agda, Coq, ...) I do not have experience with those languages which is why I am asking.

For example, on the Idris website, it is said that "types can be passed as arguments to functions" and thus, I thought, in the case of the list flattening, one could maybe simply pass the type of the list as argument and implement the desired function in a straightforward way. Is this possible?

A follow-up question would also be: Do those Families and Classes that work around this issue in haskell provide a full implementation of dependent type theory in haskell or if not, what are important differences?

Comment: FWIW, it's possible to flatten lists of arbitrary depth in Haskell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994717/126014

Comment: @Mark Seemann Ah, yes, thanks, a similar post was given in the question I linked to. However "it's usually necessary to provide the result type annotation, because otherwise ghc can't figure out where to stop recursively applying the flatten class method". I thought this might be different in a dependently typed language. One also has to use MultiParamTypeClasses, OverlappingInstances and FlexibleInstances. But yes, it's cool that it's possible at least in this way.

Comment: @Mark Seemann I edited the question with the link of your comment to be more precise.

Comment: I think the *real* reason it's not done much in Haskell is that it's just not very useful. Lists where the elements are *varying* in how nested they are **cannot** exist (e.g. `[1, 2, [[3], 4], [5]]`); non-list structures that can model this (some sort of tree) are easy to flatten. Lists nested some fixed but unknown number of times just don't tend to come up very often. Lists nested some fixed and known number of times can trivially be flattened by just composing `join`. You just don't *need* `flatten` very much in Haskell. I would imagine this would still be true in Idris.

Comment: Is the nesting always of the same depth, or can different parts of the "list" have different nesting levels, like `[1,2,[3,4]]`?

Comment: @danidiaz In this question, I assumed that the nesting level of each list is of the same depth. As far as I understood, different depth nesting is only possible with a custom data structure on purpose.

Comment: Even dependent types isn't good enough; you additionally need a type-level `case` or similar to check whether you are currently looking at a list or not, and not all dependent languages have that. (Unless, of course, you are passing the "list-or-not" information out-of-band; but if you're allowing that, then Haskell is already good enough, which makes the question a bit nonsensical.)

Comment: @Daniel Wagner Thanks, that is a good point. Which dependent type languages do have such a type `case` functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a function like that in Haskell where you don't need to specify the output type:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

type family FlatT a where
  FlatT [[a]] = FlatT [a]
  FlatT a = a

class Flat a where
  flat :: a -> FlatT a

instance Flat [a] => Flat [[a]] where
  flat xs = flat $ concat xs

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} FlatT a ~ a => Flat a where
  flat x = x

main = print $ flat [["Hello"," "],["World", "!"]]
```

One problem that still occurs is the fact that you might have a polymorphic type contained in your lists which itself might be a list. For example you can write a list of integers:

```
main = print $ flat [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

Which will give many errors about ambiguous variables. A simple fix is to add a type signature to one of the integers: `[[1,2],[3,4,5 :: Int]]`. That will fix all errors. And in some sense this error feels to me like it is unavoidable, because you can write an instance like this:

```
instance Num [Int] where
  fromInteger n = replicate (fromInteger n) (fromInteger n)
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
main = print $ [[1,2],[3,4,5 :: [Int]]]
```

Which will return:

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
```

As you can see, this unwraps one layer extra. So the number of layers that are unwrapped depends on the type you give in the signature. To me that sounds like it is not possible to avoid the type signature, even in more powerful languages.

Comment: Okay, thanks! However, I think your comment before about the Number types was useful: Indeed `print $ flat [[1,2],[3, 4]]` needs to be modified to `print $ flat [[1::Int,2],[3, 4]]` because the compiler otherwise might suspect that the num type contains another list. Perhaps you could elaborate on that?

Comment: Furthermore, the example uses TypeFamilies and in the haskell wiki (https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families), it says that "Type families are useful for generic programming, for creating highly parameterised library interfaces, and for creating interfaces with enhanced static information, much like **dependent types**."
So does this mean that this is indeed something that is finally achieved because the Haskell programmers added (something very similar to) dependent types to haskell? Because then the answer to the question still seems to be "yes".

Comment: I edited the question again to emphasize those points of interest (but also upvoted your answer).

Comment: @exchange I added a part about using numbers. And also about dependent types, standard Haskell2010 type classes themselves are a kind of type to term functions. Type families are like type to type functions. So, in some sense these are all mechanisms that enable a restricted form of dependent typing. I also think you could maybe avoid type families and use multi-parameter type classes and functional dependencies instead, but those are also not standard Haskell2010 features.

Comment: @exchange What you've been talking about is having values that depend on types (e.g. `mempty :: Semigroup a => a` is a different value depending on its type). Type classes are one simple way of doing that that have been in Haskell from the beginning. The other way round is to have types that depend on values, e.g. taking a runtime `n :: Int` and constructing a vector whose type guarantees it to have n elements, like `Vec n ()`. Haskell does not allow this directly (there are ways of simulating a lot of the things you can do with it, but not all from my understanding).

Comment: @exchange Full dependent Haskell is being worked on, but is not there yet. I think the intended reading of the sentence is "Type families are useful for ..., much like dependent types are useful for those things", it's not trying to say that type families are equivalent to dependent types (or it shouldn't be trying to say that, anyway).

Comment: @Ben thanks a lot for the additional information! Is there a website or something that tracks the progress of the work on full dependent Haskell?

Comment: @exchange we're getting a bit off-topic, but I think this is the latest status update: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXDivoj1v6w, so https://richarde.dev/pubs.html is like a status page of the research side.

Comment: @Noughtmare That's really cool! It sounds like there's real hope for an even better version of Haskell = )

Answer (score 3):

A common way in Haskell to mimic “*arbitrarily deeply nested lists*” is to use [*free monads*](https://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html).

Free monads are included in the language library, as package [Control.Monad.Free](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html).

so we can attempt to implement “*multi-level lists*” as the `MLL` type transformer:

```
import  Control.Monad
import  Control.Monad.Free

-- Multi-Level List:
type MLL = Free []

mllJoin :: [MLL a] -> MLL a
mllJoin = Free

mllWrap  :: a -> MLL a
mllWrap = return
```

Now the question is: how could we *flatten* such an object ?
Well, a possible remark is that, if the functor argument `ft` of the `Free` type constructor is an instance of the `Foldable` class, then so is `Free ft`.

Hence, as [] is foldable, so is our `MLL` type transformer.

The type of `foldr`, for example:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

can be specialized like this:

```
foldr :: (a -> acct -> acct) -> acct -> MLL a -> acct
```

with `acct` as the accumulator type.

This gives the idea to pick acct as [a], and to have `cons` as the functional argument of `foldr`. Like this:

```
mllFlatten :: MLL a -> MLL a
mllFlatten xs  =  let  fl1 = foldr (:) [] xs
                  in   mllJoin (fmap mllWrap fl1)
```

### Test program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- try build a small multilevel structure as zs:
    let  xs = (mllJoin [ mllWrap 41, mllWrap 42 ]) :: (MLL Integer)
         ys =  mllJoin [ xs, mllWrap 43 ]
         zs =  mllJoin [ mllWrap 40, ys, mllWrap 44 ]
    putStrLn $ "zs = " ++ (show zs)
    
    -- display structure of zs:
    let  zsImage = filter  (\ch -> not (elem ch "Pure Free"))  (show zs)
    putStrLn $ "zsImage = " ++ zsImage

    -- flattening zs:
    let  fzs = mllFlatten zs
    putStrLn $ "Flattened zs = " ++ (show fzs)

    -- display structure of flattened zs:
    let  fzsImage = filter  (\ch -> not (elem ch "Pure Free"))  (show fzs)
    putStrLn $ "fzsImage = " ++ fzsImage
```

### Test program output:

```
zs = Free [Pure 40,Free [Free [Pure 41,Pure 42],Pure 43],Pure 44]
zsImage = [40,[[41,42],43],44]
Flattened zs = Free [Pure 40,Pure 41,Pure 42,Pure 43,Pure 44]
fzsImage = [40,41,42,43,44]
```

Hence, it seems that fold'ing the structure does flatten it.

Answer (score 2):

Generics is a good tool for tasks like this.  If your type is an instance of `Data` you can write

```
import Data.Generics
import Control.Monad
gFind :: (MonadPlus m, Data a, Typeable b) => a -> m b
gFind = msum . map return . listify (const True)
```

So,

```
λ> gFind [[1,2],[3,4,5]] :: [Integer]
[1,2,3,4,5]
λ> gFind ((1,"b"),(2,"d","e")) :: [Integer]
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to see how it can be done in Coq, I propose here a simple solution.

```
From Coq Require Import Utf8 List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint flatten {A} (l : list (list A)) : list A :=
  match l with
  | x :: l => x ++ flatten l
  | [] => []
  end.

(* Nested list type *)
Fixpoint nlist (n : nat) (A : Type) : Type :=
  match n with
  | 0 => A
  | S n => list (nlist n A)
  end.

Fixpoint nflatten {n A} (l : nlist n A) : list A :=
  match n as m
  return nlist m A → list A
  with
  | 0 => λ x, [ x ]
  | S n => λ l, flatten (map nflatten l)
  end l.

Eval compute in
nflatten (n := 2) [
  [ 1 ; 2 ; 3 ] ;
  [ 4 ; 5 ] ;
  [] ;
  [ 6 ]
].
(* = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
     : list nat *)

Eval compute in
nflatten (n := 3) [
  [ [1] ; [2 ; 3] ] ;
  [ [4 ; 5] ] ;
  [] ;
  [ [6] ]
].
(* = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
     : list nat *)
```

I first redefine `flatten` in a naive way and then I define a type of nested lists `nlist` that comes with a natural number corresponding to the depth.
I assume that you want a constant depth in all your lists, otherwise the solution would be slightly more complicated.

Then `nflatten` will simply do a case analysis on the natural number to do the flattening.